# Can't make nVidia work in new installation (Segmentation fault at address 0xa0)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 16.04, nvidia, xorg

I'm trying to make the nvidia work in my new machine. Specifications:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GPU (6GB dedicated)
CPU:
Intel® Core™ i7 Skylake - 6700HQ 2.6 GHz, 6MB Cache (3.50 GHz com Max Turbo)
MEMORY:
32GB Memória DDR4 (2133 MHZ)
HARD DISK (HDD), SSD OU SSHD:
SSHD 1 TB com 8GB SSD
SATAE M.2:
SATAe M.2 - 480GB SATA III - 6Gb/s
TELA (LCD):
15.6" FullHD (1920 x 1080p) 16:9 LED-Backlit - (Matte)
```

The last thing I did was:

1. Preliminary step - Removing old drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt purge nvidia*  
   sudo reboot now
   ```
2. Adding the Graphics Drivers PPA (additional software source providing newer drivers versions):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Installing the recommended driver:

   ```
   sudo apt install nvidia-370
   sudo reboot now
   ```

The Ubuntu version is 16.04.1

The error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iInlD.jpg

Everything seems to be working, the folders exists, but I can't see anything, I can only access through the terminal.

Comment: @juan-antonio: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/840589/revisions) There are a few tricks in there.  If you don't get it, ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)